# PHP foreach echo

Tags: php, yii

I want to echo all content in array $dataProvider but it's error.  This is the error notice "Trying to get property of non-object".  Here's the function in Controller

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $dataProvider = Administrator::model()->findAll();
        $this->render('index',array('dataProvider'=>$dataProvider));
    }
```

and this is the View code

```
<td><?php 
        foreach ($dataProvider as $data){
            $temp = $data->applicationAdmins->app_id; //the error occur here
            if($temp!=null){
                echo $data->applicationAdmins->app->status->name;
            }
            else {
            };
        }
    ?>
</td>
```

Comment: do a `print_r($dataProvider)`

Comment: `print_r($data->applicationAdmins);` and you will get to know whether that object does have `app_id` property or not

Comment: try to use var_dump for the `$dataProvider` datas to see if there is an existing object you are repetedly calling.

Comment: thanks all, i'll try, sorry im newbie hehe

Comment: Chances are Administrator Model do not have correctly set relations applicationAdmins.

Answer (score 0):

For a clear view try using this:

```
CVarDumper::dump($dataProvider, 10, true);
```

This will show you what does `$dataProvider` contain and which property of it is an object.

Comment: thanks man, i'll try, sorry for noob question, im still newbie